# Failover appender not working for log4j2 version 2.7

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, log4j2, failover

My spring boot application uses `Kafka` as an appender for my logs using `log4j2.` The properties for the same are given below:

```
<Kafka name="kafkaAppender" topic="logs" ignoreExceptions="false" >
        <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n" />
        <Property name="bootstrap.servers">127.0.0.1:9092</Property>
    </Kafka>
    <Async name="Async" ignoreExceptions="false" >
      <AppenderRef ref="kafkaAppender"/>
    </Async>
```

The errors I get are :

```
kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-2] 2018-04-26 17:12:22,590 WARN  org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector [276] - Error in I/O with /127.0.0.1
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:238) [kafka-clients-0.8.2.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:192) [kafka-clients-0.8.2.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:191) [kafka-clients-0.8.2.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:122) [kafka-clients-0.8.2.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_144]
```

To fix the above errors I used failover appender given by log4j2 the configuration for which is given below:

```
<Failover name="Failover" primary="Async" ignoreExceptions="true" >
  <Failovers>
    <AppenderRef ref="RollingRandomAccessFile"/>
  </Failovers>
</Failover>
```

Still instead of going to the appender given in the failover, the application prints the above errors continously and the below :

```
2018-04-26 17:05:37,196 restartedMain ERROR appender Failover has no parameter that matches element Failovers
```

Is there any way to fix the issue as people on `log4j2` forums say that its a bug for Failover tag.

Answer (score 0):

There is **OPEN bug** as of *August 2019* in log4j2, which is causing the issue!

kindly find [link here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1163)